# Splitting data frame into smaller data frames based on unique column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my data frame:

```
    Quantity     Code         Value       
0       1757     08951201     717.0
1       1100     08A85800       0.0
2       2500     08A85800       0.0
3        323     08951201       0.0
4        800     08A85800       0.0
```

and i what to split this into smaller data frames created based on Code column. (E.g. this one should split into df1 with all 08951201 codes and df2 with 08A85800)

Edit:
And I'd love to have a way to merge them back into original dataframe in the same order after some value calculations im gonna perform.

Comment: why would you merge then back? you could save the original one...

Comment: you should read the [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) doc ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you could use `groupby()` on your dataframe to segregate by one column name values:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Quantity', 'Code', 'Value']
data = [[1757,     '08951201',     717.0],
 [1100,     '08A85800',       0.0],
 [2500,     '08A85800',       0.0],
 [323,    '08951201',      0.0],
 [800,    '08A85800',       0.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

groups =df.groupby(['Code'])
```

Then you can recover indices by  `groups.indices` , this will return a dict with 'Code' values as keys, and index as values. For last if you want to get every sub-dataframe you can call `group_list = list(groups)`. I suggest to do the work in 2 steps (first group by, then call list), because this way you can call other methods over the groupDataframe (`group`)

---

**EDIT**

Then if you want a particular dataframe you could call

```
 df_i = group_list[i][1]
```

`group_list[i]` is the i-th element of sub-dataframe, but it's a tupple containing `(group_val,group_df)`. where `group_val` is the value associated to this new dataframe (`'08951201'` or `'08A85800'`) and `group_df` is the new dataframe.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. I need separate Data Frames but the output of this is a list(?)

Comment: `group_list = list(groups)` is a list, then you can call `group_list[0]` wich is the first sub-dataframe, `group_list[1]` is the seccond one and so (in your example you will only have 2 but, if you have more codes, then you will have more)

Comment: ```print(type(group_list[1]))``` gives me ```<class 'tuple'>```

Comment: Sorry my bad, you have to call `group_list[0][1]` (the first index is group number, the seccond one is the order of DF inside the tuple). The first element in the tuple is the code value associated the seccond one is the dataframe

Comment: @Julian see the edit, I've corrected the code to get wat you wanted

Comment: Sorry, I had to go offline. Anyway, thank you so much for your time. This is exactly what I needed, 10/10 answer.

Comment: no problem! I've just mentioned you to be notiffied about the changes, didn't realize you were the OP

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and apply your custom function to process your sub dataframe:

```
groups = df.groupby('Code')
print(list(groups))

# Output:
[('08951201',    Quantity      Code  Value
0      1757  08951201  717.0
3       323  08951201    0.0),

('08A85800',    Quantity      Code  Value
1      1100  08A85800    0.0
2      2500  08A85800    0.0
4       800  08A85800    0.0)]
```

Now suppose you want to `sum` by `Value`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Code')['Value'].sum()
Code
08951201    717.0
08A85800      0.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```